# Using plpgsql's `RETURN SETOF` to return a simple query with join

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm getting trouble with returning values in postgresql, i created a function like this (EDITED):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetComissionamento(pv varchar(50))
RETURNS SETOF tb_comissionamentos AS
$$
BEGIN
SELECT com.* FROM tb_vendas as vendas 
 INNER JOIN tb_pagamentos as pg on vendas.id_venda = pg.id_venda
 INNER JOIN tb_comissionamentos as com on vendas.id_venda = com.id_venda 
    AND com.id_pagamento = pg.id_pagamento
 WHERE id_venda_imobiliaria = pv;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And i want to return the data on the table tb_comissionamento as the query says.
What should i do? When i call the function i got the error message:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad.

1. This should be a `VIEW` instead of a function

Like this,

```
CREATE VIEW GetComissionamento AS 
SELECT com.* FROM tb_vendas as vendas 
     INNER JOIN tb_pagamentos as pg on vendas.id_venda = pg.id_venda
     INNER JOIN tb_comissionamentos as com on vendas.id_venda = com.id_venda 
        AND com.id_pagamento = pg.id_pagamento;
```

And then (where $pv is your value),

```
SELECT *
FROM GetComissionamento
WHERE id_venda_imobiliaria = $pv;
```

2. If you're going to make this simple thing a function use `sql` instead of `plpgsql`

Like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetComissionamento(varchar(50))
RETURNS tb_comissionamentos AS $$
SELECT com.* FROM tb_vendas as vendas 
 INNER JOIN tb_pagamentos as pg on vendas.id_venda = pg.id_venda
 INNER JOIN tb_comissionamentos as com on vendas.id_venda = com.id_venda 
    AND com.id_pagamento = pg.id_pagamento
 WHERE id_venda_imobiliaria = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

3. If you're going to keep it as a plpgsql use `RETURN QUERY`.

Like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetComissionamento (pv varchar(50))
RETURNS tb_comissionamentos AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
     SELECT com.* FROM tb_vendas as vendas 
     INNER JOIN tb_pagamentos as pg on vendas.id_venda = pg.id_venda
     INNER JOIN tb_comissionamentos as com on vendas.id_venda = com.id_venda 
        AND com.id_pagamento = pg.id_pagamento
     WHERE id_venda_imobiliaria = pv;
  -- error checking or whatever
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, got the error, forgot the return query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetComissionamento(pv varchar(50))
RETURNS SETOF tb_comissionamentos AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT com.* FROM tb_vendas as vendas 
 INNER JOIN tb_pagamentos as pg on vendas.id_venda = pg.id_venda
 INNER JOIN tb_comissionamentos as com on vendas.id_venda = com.id_venda 
    AND com.id_pagamento = pg.id_pagamento
 WHERE id_venda_imobiliaria = pv;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Look at my answer before you go with this. =)

Comment: Also consider asking these questions on http://dba.stackexchange.com in the future.